# bukkit - Prevent player from running command when in combat

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So I'm developing a Java Plugin and I need to do something like the KitPvP servers do these days, the player selects a kit, and then they are only allowed to get a kit again once they've died.

I've tried this using strings to check if the player is in command, but I really don't know what/"how" to do with them. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list to check if the player has got the kit in "this life".
For example in your main plugin class or in your command class you could add a static member like this:

```
public static ArrayList<UUID> usedKit = new ArrayList<UUID>();
```

In the onCommand() method you can check if the player hasn't got his kit yet:

```
if (!usedKit.contains(player.getUniqueId())) {

    // Code to give the kit here...

    usedKit.add(player.getUniqueId()); // Adds the player to the list
} else
    player.sendMessage("You already got your kit.");
return true;
```

When the player dies you have to remove him from the list:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent event) {
    if (usedKit.contains(event.getPlayer().getUniqueId()))
        usedKit.remove(event.getPlayer().getUniqueId());
}
```

I know that this answer is similar to Kerooker's but you should try to use UniqueIds since you can change your name in minecraft.

Comment: Nice! How to get this list in my other classes?

Comment: Too much spoonfeed, but a nice answer. Just one point, it's better to access the list via methods than via the static variable only.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a list containing the names of the players that have already used the kits

```
List<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then whenever they use the command, you check if the player is inside your list

```
boolean isInList = players.contain(yourPlayer.getName());
```

You can check that when you handle the command

```
if (isInList) {
    player.sendMessage("You must die to use this again!");
    return true; //To commandExecutor
}
```

If the player is not in the list, add him to the list and give the kit

```
players.add(yourPlayer.getName());
//Give the kit
```

Whenever a player die, you should try to remove his name from the List.

```
@EventHandler
public void onDeath(PlayerDeathEvent e) {
//Remove player from the list
}
```

---

Note that inside a `onCommand`, you have the following attributes of a command: `CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args`.

The sender argument may be your player, and you can check that by

```
if (sender instanceof Player) {
Player commandPlayer = (Player) sender;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! yes, but how can I pass this list through all my classes? I have one class to each kit.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you use the Spigot API and you'r probably searching for something like this [PlayerDeathEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/entity/PlayerDeathEvent.html)

This gets triggered everytime a Player dies and you can compare them with your Players list and update the [permissions(bukkit)](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Developing_a_permissions_plugin/de) [permission(spiggot)](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/tutorial-giving-removing-player-permissions.53840/).

Hopefully this answered your question.

Comment: I assume that you didn't read my question. I'm not using Spigot and how should I make the command inacessible? I know that I should reset it on the PlayerDeathEvent, but how? That's what I don't know.

Comment: What I really don't know is what you didn't said basically :P, how to make this list, what this list contains? @Nordiii

Comment: As far as I know the development of bukkit stopped? Updated answer with bukkit link.

Comment: i'm using 1.7.10. And if you could explain what I preveously said.

Comment: Both links about permissions explain how you can set/unset permissions!
Just unset them when used and set them when died.

Comment: I know, just how to remove the permission like, onKit? There's no method for that.

Comment: `attachment.setPermission(permissionName,false);`
or
`attachment.unsetPermission(permissionName);` ?

this will remove the permission(also in the link)

As I don't know how "onKit|KitPVP" removes their permission I assume they do this the same way.

I won't answer on another unclear question as I would say the permission links give you everything you need to set players permission for your own Plugin:
It just feels like you'r to lazy to read/test this method.

Comment: It feels that the other solutions are more appropriate and work better, but thank you!